# How to Convert Dask DataFrame Into List of Dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, parallel-processing, dask

I need to convert a dask dataframe into a list of dictionaries as the response for an API endpoint. I know I can convert the dask dataframe to pandas, and then from there I can convert to dictionary, but it would be better to map each partition to a dict, and then concatenate.

What I tried:

```
df = dd.read_csv(path, usecols=cols)

dd.compute(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
import dask.bag as db
db.from_delayed(df.map_partitions(pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records'
    ).to_delayed())
```

which gives you a [bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag.html) which you could compute (if it fits in memory) or otherwise manipulate.

Note that to_delayed/from_delayed should not be necessary, there is also a `to_bag` method, but it doesn't seem to do the right thing.

Also, you are not really getting much from the `dataframe` model here, you may want to start with [`db.read_text`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.read_text) and the builtin CSV module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data=list(df.map_partitions(lambda x:x.to_dict(orient="records")))
```

It will return a list of dictionaries wherein each row will be converted to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **Kunal Bafna** is easiest to implement, and has fewer dependencies.

```
data=list(df.map_partitions(lambda x:x.to_dict(orient="records")))
```